# Time difference between two machine clocks?

Tags: windows-server-2008, time, time-synchronization

Is it possible to measure or some other way find out the difference in clock/time between two windows 2k8 r2 machines?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, install [ntpd](http://www.meinberg.de/english/sw/ntp.htm). Then add to server your Windows machine. Then run ntpq:

```
ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
+x.x.x.x          x.x.x.x        2 u 1011 1024  377    0.632   -6.836   0.072
```

Comment: Where to install this ntpd? Should we install this on both machines that we compare? On what (cli,gui) screen and which computer we run the query above?